# Rescue git pull

Tags: git, bash, shell

I use `git pull` to ensure that local repos are up to date. However, `git pull` sometimes fails. `git pull` fails if you have uncommitted changes. Is there a git, or shell, option to ensure that if the commands fails the rest of the script continues?

The script currently is:

```
if [ -d "some-repo" ]; then
  cd "some-repo"
  git pull
  #RESCUE????
else
  git clone git@github.com:USERNAME/some-repo.git
  cd "some-repo"
fi
```

I don't want to checkout a branch, and I don't really care about the work going on in different branches. I know it is possible to do a `git reset --hard`, or use a `--force` command but i want to make sure it is safe, and that code doesn't get lost.

Comment: Here is the tricky thing with your script: `git pull` is actually a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` of the newly updated tracking branch into its local branch counterpart.  It is possible that the fetch could fail, but it is also possible that the merge could fail.  So I think you would need to account for the type of failure.

Comment: You could do a preventive `git stash` before every `git pull` you make, followed by a `git stash pop`. Bear in mind that conflicts might show up when you `git stash pop` though.

Comment: @cfz42 I like this idea. If there is a conflict, pop won't actually pop the stash, so your changes are safe.

Comment: I just want to mention that if I wasn't programming with ruby, i might of described this as a try / catch git pull.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `git pull` inside an `if` clause:

```
if git pull; then
    # Here, git has successfully pulled
else
    # Here goes code for dealing with a failed pull
fi
```

Comment: `set -e` is the opposite of what OP requested

Comment: I changed `do` to `then`, and `done` to `fi`, to make it work with my shell. I think it is a cool, shell based way, of overriding git pull's exit. It git pull must return something like true if it worked and false if it didn't. I will still need to deal with a failed pull.

Comment: Yes, bash uses "if then else fi" in conditionals, but loops are "for do done". I got confused :p But what you said about "git pull must return something like true", that's right. In Unix, all commands return a value to the operating system when they terminate. The convention is that this value is 0 when the program was successful, and nonzero when something bad happens (but not all programs follow this convention). Anyway, the shell has access to this value (it's stored in the variable `$?` right after you call `git pull`), and uses it to decide which branch of the conditional to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you can just add these 2 lines before you pull the repo.

`git add .
 git commit -am "sync repo"`

This should work as long as there's no merge conflict.

Comment: I don't really want to fill the git history with messages of "sync repo". It would make tracking changes more harder. I don't really feel like I should commit whatever random stuff I have in the repo. I try to be more intentional about what I commit, like "add discrete decoupled thing".

Answer (score 0):

In you case I think *git fetch* is better. *git pull* always merge the remote tracking branch into your current HEAD. It could be a non-fast-forward merge, which may make your checked-out branch's history a bit confusing if you are co-working with others. By *git fetch* you just update the remote tracking branch, and later you can decide how to deal with the new commits, merge them all or just cherry-pick some to your master branch.